# How would I do this POST request in Swift (w/ PHP & mySQL) using a GET request?

Tags: php, json, swift, post, get

I am utilizing a Swift POST method with PHP and a mysql query inside that PHP statement, but I'd like to do the same thing using a GET method.

My code executes flawlessly 90% of the time, but for some reason it occasionally gets buggy and doesn't retrieve any JSON objects. I wanted to try the same thing using GET to see if the bugs stop happening.

Below is my Swift code:

```
    let loadSongsID = self.partyID[0]


    let bodyData = "partyID=\(loadSongsID)" //To get them in php: $_POST['name']


    let songURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://myserverURL/loadSongsIntoParty.php")!
    var postData:NSData = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    var songsRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:songURL)
    songsRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    songsRequest.HTTPBody = postData

    var responseError: NSError?
    var response: NSURLResponse?


    var urlData: NSData! = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(songsRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: &responseError)

    var allSongs: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &responseError)


    if let songsJson = allSongs as? Array<AnyObject> {

        println(songsJson)


        for index in 0...songsJson.count-1 {

            let indivSong : AnyObject? = songsJson[index]

            let collection = indivSong! as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            let track : AnyObject! = collection["track"]
            let artist : AnyObject! = collection["artist"]
            let trackURI : AnyObject! = collection["trackURI"]
            let vote: AnyObject! = collection["vcount"]

            self.tracks.append(track as String)
            self.names.append(artist as String)
            self.tracksURI.append(trackURI as String)
            self.votes.append(vote as String)

        }

    }
```

My PHP:

```
  <?php

  // Create connection                                                            
  $con = mysqli_connect("######", "######", "######", "#######");


  // Check connection                                                             
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 // Change character set to utf8                                                 
 mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

 $ID = $_POST['partyID'];

 $sql = "select track, artist, trackURI, vcount from votes where PID = '$ID'";

 // Check to see if there are results                                            
 if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

// If so, then create a results array and a temporary one to hold date          

$resultArray = array();
$tempArray   = array();

// loop through each row in the result set                                      
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    //Add each row into our results array                                           
    $tempArray = $row;

    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}

// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results                     
echo json_encode($resultArray);
 }


 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: why not you using alamofire?

Comment: I would not suggest shifting from `POST` to `GET` as an attempt to fix this problem. You must diagnose _why_ the `POST` is failing. You're not looking at response codes, error objects, etc., so you're flying blind here. Unrelated, but you should never use synchronous requests. Also, never take `$_POST` variable and insert it into SQL without doing `mysqli_real_escape_string`.